# c-icap and attachment file

Tags: c++, c, open-source

I want to hook the attachment files. For instance, when the user try to attach file using webmail or something else , i want too hook the attachment file. I analysed the echo service, in the `echo_check_preview_handler` function i can hook the content of the data. But i want to hook attachment file. I searched some c-icap module (squidclamav and yara), but i didn't find this ability. From the simple_api.c code , i used the below code but i can only hook the ascii file with  data->body->filename.

```
data->body = ci_simple_file_new(0);
     if ((SEND_PERCENT_BYTES >= 0) && (START_SEND_AFTER == 0))
     {
        ci_req_unlock_data(req);
        ci_simple_file_lock_all(data->body);
     }

if (!data->body)
        return CI_ERROR;
       if (ci_simple_file_write(data->body, preview_data, preview_data_len,  ci_req_hasalldata(req)) == CI_ERROR)
               return CI_ERROR;
```

So how can i achive this ? Is there any example c-icap module or documentation or code block ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not do it in preview_handler, instead here is what you should do:

in preview_handler - return CI_MOD_CONTINUE

then implement io where you do ci_simple_file_write ...

then in end of data handler you can implement your analysis.

Here is a comment from services.h which briefly explains the life-cycle of a c-icap plugin:

- Is the structure  which implements a service
  *
- To implement a service someones needs to implement the member
  functions of this struct. These functions
- will be called by c-icap as follows:
- - New request arrives for this service  ->  The
    ci_service_module::mod_init_request_data called
- - The icap client sends preview data -> The
    ci_service_module::mod_check_preview_handler called.
- If this function return CI_MOD_ALLOW204 the ICAP transaction
  stops here. If this function return
- CI_MOD_CONTINUE the ICAP client will send the rest body data if exists.
- - The client starts sends more data ->
    ci_service_module::mod_service_io called multiple times until the
- client has send all the body data. The service can start send
  data using this function to the client
- before all data has received
- - The client has send all data -> the
    ci_service_module::mod_end_of_data_handler called
- - The client waits to read the rest data from c-icap ->
    ci_service_module::mod_service_io called multiple
- times until all the body data send to the client
  */

and no - you can't directly hook the attachment, but you'll have to parse-out the attachment file from the content you write via ci_simple_file API.

Answer (score 0):

> For instance, when the user try to attach file using webmail or something else , i want too hook the attachment file

You need to hook HTTP Request contains files as it's body data.

So your target is **REQMOD** ICAP Request.

Here are 3 hints for you.

1. in preview, check body magic, identify body type as 'file data' (**ci_magic_data_type_ext** helps).
2. in service_io, read all the data while **iseof** is not true(**ci_simple_file..** functions helps).
3. in end_of_data, modify or check the file as **ci_simple_file** object.

keep in mind the file data is usually gzip or deflate compressed.

c-icap document can be generated with **make doc**.

Comment: The information in your comments should be in the post itself. Use the edit feature.